# changing content type icons in Plone with Sunburst theme

Tags: icons, plone

I'd like to change the default icons for the Folder and Document types.  Running Plone 4.2 with Sunburst.  I tried customizing the portal_skins/plone_images/folder_icon.png to hold the file myfolder.png but this had no effect.

I've also tried setting the Icon property on the Folder type to point to an alternate file following what I see in the Icon property of other types, ${portal_url}/myfile.png.  If I then go to http://mysite.com/myfolder/myfile.png, I see the icon, but it does not show up in contents listings -- next to the text "myfolder" there is still the normal folder icon.

I also tried going in and changing the URL in a custom copy of the sunburst theme where it is using a url of contenttypes-sprite.png, but that just made the icons go away.

I would be pulling my hair out if there were any left.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me why I stay away from front-end design. :-) Did you use your browser dev tools to check what the original name of the icon is? Is it using the `contenttypes-sprite.png` image?

Comment: The changed icon appeared as an IMG in the HTML, using the correct name.  But something in the CSS (?) seemed to be overriding it, and it didn't appear on the page.  You hover over a blank area just before the word "Folder" and the text "Folder:" pops up, but there's no image.

Comment: Look for a background CSS entry, with perhaps an offset..

Comment: I've tried altering that entry.  If this matters, I didn't make a whole custom copy of the sunburst theme, just added a copy of public.css to the portal_skins/custom area and tampered with the URL and offset in the lines below, reducing both offsets to 0px and using /myfile.png as the background:`.icons-on .contenttype-folder {
    background: no-repeat transparent 0px -644px url(contenttypes-sprite.png);
}`

Comment: Sorry, I take back the comment about the IMG tag appearing -- it was from a section of the HTML other than the content listing.  (Blush.)

Comment: The two relevant fragments of output HTML (for the record) are at [link](http://snipt.org/zshh3)

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the 'contenttypes-sprite.png', edit it with an image-manipulation-program of your choice (mine is GIMP) to 'overpaint' the folder-icon right in the sprite and put it in a skins-folder of your product (or in the ZMI's custom-folder). Clear browsercache when reloading.

With Plone-4.2.0 this works perfectly fine, oddly with Plone-4.2.1 I needed to adjust the background-positions slightly.